# Missing values of map(key, value) in Freemarker when access randomly?

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm having a strange problem with Freemarker map. My example is meant to display a list of cars with the associated owners' name:

`Car(id,name,ownerId)`

`User(id,name)`

Notice that the `ownerId` is the only bridge I can access `owner` from `car`. For some reasons, we don't create hibernate relation for these domains.

I added to model a list `carList` of `Car(id,name,ownerId)` and a `Map<String, String> map` which contains `(userId, name)` of **all** users.. It's because Freemarker only accept Map with key of type String.

While looping through the carList, I try to get the owner name through the map.

```
<#list carList as car>
  ${map?values[car.ownerId]} - ${car.ownerId}<br/>
</#list>
```

But the strange thing is that the result I got:

```
Tom - 1
Jerry - 2
Jerry - 2
David - 4
- 5
- 5
```

The name of user "5" is missing, but it exists in the database. Besides, when I loop through the map the result is right:

```
<#list map?keys as key>
  ${key} - ${map[key]}
</#list>
```

The results:

```
1 - Tom
2 - Jerry
3 - Mickey
4 - David
5 - Mike
```

The missing name happens for only a specific user. Do anyone know what is missing here?

Comment: Notice: there is not many user & car (no more than 100 for both) so that I think it's not a problem loading them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning: contains some speculation!**

I believe that part of your problem is that you use `map?values[car.ownerId]` in order to retrieve the user's names. `map?values` gives you the sequence of values of your `map` hash (see [FreeMarker documentation](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html)), which happens to be the **sequence** of usernames. Then you access its elements by index (not by userId!), which returns usernames for most of the cases, but not when the `userId` reaches the size of your map, because in your `map` hash with 5 elements, the value sequence can only be indexed from 0 to 4, and your `userId` has values 1 to 5.

If my theory is correct, then maybe using `map[car.ownerId?c]` will solve your problem (note: I assumed that `car.ownerId` is something numeric, and because the keys in your `map` hash are strings I used the [`?c` built-in](http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_c) to convert the numbers into an unformatted strings).

Comment: it works! But I don't know how it works. Can you give me some resources?

Comment: Which part exactly don't you understand? In general, it's a good idea to read throught the excellent FreeMarker documentation (http://freemarker.org/docs/index.html), in your case especially the part about retrieving data from a hash (http://freemarker.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_var_hash).

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Chaquotay is correct, though I want to add another way to work around this trouble. Since the application function naturally when use the map as a simple list, we can loop it over, compare the result and print if equality happens. It's kind of dirty, but it works.

```
<#list carList  as car>
  ${car.ownerId} - 
  <#list map?keys as user_id>
    <#if car.ownerId == user_id>${map[user_id]}</#if>
  </#list>
  <br />
</#list>
```